# IF Statement Looping Php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with that script using the simulation calculation:

```
    $no3=+1;
    for ($i=0; $i<36; $i++) 

{
```

$ No = + 1; 
for ($ i = 0; $ i <36; $ i ++) {

enter code here

$ No3 ++;
}

Example :

No  GradeA  GradeB   Total
1   5       5       10
2   10      5       15
3   15      5       20
4   20      5       25
5   25      5       30
6   30      5       35
7   35      5       40
8   40      5       45
9   45      5       50
10  50      5       55
11  55      5       60
12  60      5       65
13  65      5       70
14  70      10      80
15  80      10      90
16  90      10      100
17  100 10 110  
18  110  10 120
19  120 10 130
20  130 10 140
21  140 10 150
22 150 10 160
23 160 10 170
24 170 10 180  
25 180  10 190 
26 190 20 210
27 210 20 230
28 230 20 250
29 250 20 270
30 270 20 290
31 290 20 310
32 310 20 330
33 330 20 350
34 350 20 370
35 370 20 390
36 380 20 410

```
$no3++;
}
```

how do I make the numbers 12,24 and 36 there is the text

Comment: can you describe your question properly? What you have tried? and exactly what you want?

Comment: Question is completely unclear.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for modulus (modulo) - > http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: that is not a valid output of `for ($i=0; $i<36; $i++)`. (1) it will start with `0` ( `$i=0`) and (2) it will end at `35` (`$i<36`)

Comment: You want something like this:- https://eval.in/717643   ?

Comment: previous question I have yet to find a solution. is my next question. Please help

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

this is answer for your [secound question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755097/how-looping-if-else-with-script-php#41755097) to

```
<?php
$two = 5;

$three = 5;

$four = 10;

$mod = 14;

for ($i = 1; $i <=36; $i ++) {
    echo $i."\t".$two."\t".$three."\t".$four."\n";
    
    if($i % $mod == 0){
        $three *= 2;
    }
    
    $two += $three;
    $four += $three;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have a slight correction to number 13 and so I change to<br>

12 60 5 65<br>
13 65 5 80<br>
14 80 10 90<br>
15 onwards<br>
24 170 10 180<br>
25 180 10 200<br>
26 200 20 220<br>
27 220 20 240<br>
28 onwards<br>
36 finish<br>